# Craft 3 Image doesn't change after save when editing from matrix

Tags: craft3, image

when I edit an image in the image matrix block and save the asset, the changes doesn't affect the image thumbnail preview. The thumbnail preview changes only If I save the page.

[Video of the issue.](https://youtu.be/b1DEVdrkh98)

Craft version: 3.1.24

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Can you file an issue here for it along with that video? https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues Going to go ahead and vote to close this here as a bug report.

Comment: Done!
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4217